# How do wildcards get set when building eglibc?

Tags: debian, glibc, dpkg, debhelper

I am attempting to build the eglibc-2.11.2 package from source.  Stupidly or not, I'm trying to backport it to Debian Lenny, mainly so I can build other things that require it without having to upgrade my whole system past stable.  (Whether this is a good idea is an exercise for the reader.)  I am using the Debianized source from sid.

When I execute dpkg-buildpackage, the package builds, but I eventually get the following error when it is running dh-shlibdeps.

```
dh-shlibdeps: warning: can't parse dependency #PACKAGE# (>> 2.11)
dh-shlibdeps: error: invalid dependency got generated: #PACKAGE# (>> 2.11)
```

(I'm slightly paraphrasing because, unfortunately, the error message has scrolled out of my `screen` buffer during my troubleshooting session, and this is a long build.)

It is of course quite possible that I have some other package out of date.  I updated debhelper from backports, so it is at version 8.0, but that didn't help.  What would solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#PACKAGE#` is substituted by `dpkg-gensymbols`, part of `dpkg-dev`, as of 1.15.0. Looks like lenny only had 1.14.29.

Backporting dpkg/dpkg-dev to 1.15.0 will probably resolve this particular issue.

Comment: I have not yet had a chance to follow this process to completion, but it's looking good so far.  Backporting dpkg was not quite as straightforward as hoped, but I was able to do so successfully with a few minor edits to the source.  The C libraries seemed to build, and packages were created.  I haven't had a chance yet to babysit the install of all the packages, but I'm definitely further along than I was.  Further updates as events warrant...

Comment: I have a lot more dependencies to figure out for what I am trying to do, but this part seems to be spot on.